# The bigger the domain, the smaller the first eigenvalue - $\lambda(M_2) \leq \lambda(M_1)$ on the Laplacian

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

I know it is probably a silly question, but is there anyone could help me to complete of the corollary $3.1$ of that [document](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/14-15/summer-research14/mini-conf/SpectralGeometryReport.pdf)? I pass a lot of time to try understanding the problem, but I can't advance on the subject.

> Corollary $3.1$. If $M_1 \subset M_2$, then $$\lambda(M_2) \leq
>  \lambda(M_1),$$ *i.e. the bigger the domain, the smaller the first
>   eigenvalue.*
>
> **Proof.**  $$\lambda_1(M_1)=\min \{E(u), u \in C^{\infty}(M_1) \}$$
>
> But then, $u \in C^{\infty}(M_1)$, $u=0$ on $M_2$, and
>   $$\lambda_1(M_2)=\min \{E(u), u \in C^{\infty}(M_2) \}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda(M)$ ? How an eigenvalue can be attached to a domain ? Is it through a Laplacian ?

Comment: @JeanMarie All notation is explained in the document, please check it out

Comment: All right, I did not notice this document. But, nevertheless, your title or the beginning of your text should contain the central word "laplacian". If you do research, it's a basic principle that all the important keywords are present. Redundancy is at the base of all human interchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bit confusing what they wrote, bordering on incorrect. I'm sure you can find a better reference for these things.

The idea is to use the theorem that $ \lambda_1(M) \leq E(u) / \langle u,  u \rangle = \| \nabla u \|^2 / \| u \|^2 $ for any sufficiently nice $ u $ (it does not have to be $ C^\infty $).

Let $ \varphi_1 \in C^\infty(M_1) $ be the eigenvector corresponding  to $ \lambda_1(M_1) $. By extending by $ 0 $, $\varphi_1 $ defines a piecewise differentiable function $ \widetilde \varphi_1 $ on $ M_2 $. It is not $ C^\infty $.  Now use the theorem:
$$
\lambda_1(M_2) \leq \| \nabla \widetilde \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} / \| \widetilde \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} = \| \nabla \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1} / \|  \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1}= \lambda_1(M_1)
$$ 
I put subscripts on the norms $ \| \cdot \|_{M_i} $ to indicate in which space it is taken.
The equality $ \| \nabla \widetilde \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} / \| \widetilde \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} = \| \nabla \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1} / \|  \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1} $ is because $ \widetilde \varphi_1 $ has support in $ M_1 $ and will be obvious if you write out each side in terms of integrals.

EDIT: Fixed a bunch of typos.

Comment: BTW, you have to write $\lambda_1(M) \leq E(u) / \langle u,  u \rangle = \| \nabla u \|^2 / \| u \|^2$

Comment: Right, typo. Thank you.

Comment: And your result is right, but you have to write $\lambda_1(M_2) \leq \| \nabla \widetilde  \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} / \| \widetilde \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_2} = \| \nabla \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1} / \|  \varphi_1 \|^2_{M_1}= \lambda_1(M_1)$

Comment: Another typo. Thank you.